# How to search in files and output discoveries only if they match both files

Tags: linux, bash

I want to search for a string (which I don't know unless I look inside the files) on Linux command-line.

Example:

- A file 1 with text inside
- A file 2 with text inside
- In both files the word "Apple" is existent.

I want to echo this word (which exists in both files) in a file or store it in a variable.

How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to find all the words which are in both files?

Comment: there should be a comparison between these files, and if the word (in my example "apple" is found in both files) i want to work further with it. echo it on commandline or store it in a variable.

Comment: A little more specification would be helpful. Are the files one fixed case word, no diacritics, no whitespace and punctuation per line, or do you want to do something intricate like 'human' texts with different cases, punctuations or diacritics etcetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all the unique words in a file using:

```
grep -o -E '\w+' filename | sort -u
```

where `-E '\w+'` is matching words and `-o` outputs the matching parts.  We can then use the `join` command which identifies matching lines in two files, along with process substitution to pass in the results of our word finder:

```
join <(grep -o -E '\w+' filename1 | sort -u) <(grep -o -E '\w+' filename2 | sort -u)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicates whiten a single file you could use `cat file1 file2 |sort | uniq -d`

Comment: Each line can (most likely) contain more than one word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input_one.txt 
FIREFOX a
FIREFOX b
Firefox a
firefox b

$ cat input_two.txt 
CHROME a
FIREFOX a
EXPLORER a

$ while read line; do grep "$line" input_two.txt ; done < input_one.txt 
FIREFOX a
```

Explanation:

`while` will loop every line with `input_two.txt` file as input and will store the temporary line in the `line` variable.

In every line will search for it in the `input_one.txt` file and `-o` option will make to print only the matched part.

EDIT: See comments

Comment: It is really inefficient to call `grep` for each line of the input file. And each line can (most likely) contain more than one word. Also note that `$line` is a subject to word-splitting and that it will be interpreted as a regex by `grep`, not as a fixed string.

Comment: @PesaThe As of more-than-one-word I've edited to support it.

Comment: No, you didn't really. But it's unclear from the question so I wouldn't care about that specifically.

Comment: agreed that it is unclear from question, but, why haven't I?

Comment: The way I understood "words" in the question, let's consider two files `one`: `firefox chrome` and `two`: `explorer\nfirefox`. I would expect to get `firefox`. [borrible's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075808/6176817), for example, outputs as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the script to handle this.
You need loop a word on file 1, in the loop use grep command (grep -nwr "" -e "$word") to find a word in file 2.
If match, echo a word.